# Dynamic method calling in ruby through user input doesn't work

Tags: ruby, dynamic, methods, send

Hello I have the following simple piece of code

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

input = gets.downcase.chomp.to_sym

send input

def abc

   puts "Hi"

end
```

When I run the script and type abc I get

```
test.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `abc' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

using ruby 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

def abc
  puts "Hi"
end

input = gets.downcase.chomp.to_sym
send input
```

Hope the code makes sense.